AttributeError: 'Exa' object has no attribute 'encontrar_similares' al intentar usar método en Python
I encountered an error while trying to use the tool. This was the error: 'Exa' object has no attribute 'encontrar_similares'.
Tool encontrar_similares accepts these inputs: Busca por páginas similares a la URL dada.
La URL ingresada debe ser entregada por ´buscar´
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process
import os
from tools import ExaSearchToolSet


os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = 'https://api.groq.com/openai/v1' 
os.environ["OPENAI_MODEL_NAME"] = 'llama3-70b-8192' 

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'gsk_tbTlHc9UfnGn8ZWm01XhWGdyb3

# Code snippet to be explained 
Query = 'Realiza las preguntas para una encuenta, sobre el porque la gente elige su sabor de helado' 

# Define the explainer agent 
investigador = Agent( 
role="Generacion de preguntas", 
goal="Crear un cuestionario que captura lo que hace un sabor de helado irresistible", 
backstory=" Ha trabajado en diversas cocinas alrededor del mundo, desarrollando una profunda comprensión de los sabores y sus combinaciones. Su pasión por el helado lo llevó a querer entender científicamente por qué ciertos sabores nos encantan",
tools = ExaSearchToolSet.tools(),
verbose=True,
allow_delegation=False 
)

# Define the blog writer agent 
analista = Agent( 
role="Analista", 
goal="Diseñar preguntas que revelen los motivaciones psicológicas detrás de las elecciones de sabor.", 
backstory="Ha estudiado extensamente cómo los factores emocionales, sociales y culturales influyen en nuestras decisiones de compra. Cree que el helado es más que un simple postre, es una experiencia sensorial y emocional.", 
verbose=True, 
allow_delegation=False 
) 

# Task to explain the code snippet 
recopilacion_datos = Task( 
description=f"realiza una búsqueda exhaustiva en páginas web para identificar y recopilar preguntas comunes y estudios relacionados con la elección de sabores de helado. Esto incluye investigar cómo diferentes factores (como la textura, el aroma, la presentación) influyen en la preferencia de sabores ", 
agent=investigador, 
expected_output="Un conjunto de preguntas que han sido utilizadas en investigaciones previas o encuestas sobre la elección de sabores de helado, así como un resumen de los factores que se han encontrado relevantes en estas investigaciones." 
) 

# Task to write a blog post based on the explanation 
design_preguntas = Task( 
description=f"Diseña preguntas para una encuesta que exploren las motivaciones psicológicas detrás de la elección de sabores de helado. Considera factores emocionales, sociales y culturales al formular las preguntas para revelar las razones subyacentes por las que las personas prefieren ciertos sabores.", 
agent=analista, 
expected_output="Un cuestionario detallado con preguntas que aborden aspectos emocionales y psicológicos relacionados con la elección de sabores de helado, acompañado de una breve justificación de por qué cada pregunta es relevante para entender las motivaciones detrás de las elecciones." 
) 

# Define the crew and process 
crew = Crew( 
agents=[investigador, analista],
tasks=[recopilacion_datos, design_preguntas], 
verbose=2, 
process=Process.sequential )

# Execute the process and print the output 
output = crew.kickoff() 
print(output)

import os
from exa_py import Exa
from langchain.agents import tool

# Inicializar la API de Exa
exa = Exa(api_key="093045b2-6cd6-4a6a-9b7d-17e9b876c354")

class ExaSearchToolSet:

    @staticmethod
    def exa():
        return exa

    @tool
    def buscar(query: str):
        "Busca una página basada en el query"
        return ExaSearchToolSet.exa().search(f"{query}", use_autoprompt=True, num_results=3)

    @tool
    def encontrar_similares(url: str):
        """Busca por páginas similares a la URL dada.
        La URL ingresada debe ser entregada por ´buscar´"""
        return ExaSearchToolSet.exa().encontrar_similares(url, num_results=3)

    @tool
    def obtener_contenido(ids: str):
        """Obtén contenido de una página web
        Los ids deben pasarse como una lista, una lista de identificadores devueltos desde `buscar`"""
        
        ids = eval(ids)
        contents = ExaSearchToolSet.exa().get_contents(ids)
        contents = contents.split("URL:")
        contents = [content[:1000] for content in contents]
        return "\n\n".join(contents)

    @staticmethod
    def tools():
        return [
            ExaSearchToolSet.buscar,
            ExaSearchToolSet.encontrar_similares,
            ExaSearchToolSet.obtener_contenido
        ]


I tried to use the encontrar_similares method from the Exa class in my code. I expected this method to find and return similar web pages based on a given URL. The code snippet attempts to invoke this method as part of a process to generate survey questions related to ice cream flavor preferences. However, when running the code, I encountered an error indicating that the Exa object has no attribute 'encontrar_similares'.
I expected the code to execute without errors, retrieving similar web pages as intended, so I could continue the process of generating and refining the survey questions.
